# My Data from firestore can't add to MPAndroidChart(PieChart)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, mpandroidchart

I tried to add the size of my collection from fire Store to MPAndroidChart pie chart, but the data that I've got doesn't add to the PieEntry. I hope there is a solution for this. Thank You! (Sorry for my bad english)

```
//PieChart
    reportingPieChart = findViewById(R.id.reportPiechart);

    //adding data
    final ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    //getting data from firebase
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    String a = "Active";
    String w = "Withdrawn";
    String p = "Pending";
    String s = "Sold";

    fStore.collection("Listing").whereEqualTo("lStatus", a).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(task.getResult().size()))/*number of active*/, "Active")); //getting active in listing
           // Log.d("tag","Size: " + size);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please consol.log(task) and share the output?

Comment: D/tag: Size: 1, this is the output

Comment: Sorry, I asked for console.log(task). could you please share that output?

Comment: I already found a solution, I change to another library. Thank You for your time :)